# Stop MediaPlayer when minimizing

Tags: java, android, media-player

```
    button4 = findViewById(R.id.button4);

    musicSound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.music);
    buttonClick(); }

private Button button4;
private MediaPlayer musicSound;

public void buttonClick() {
    button4.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    soundPlay(musicSound);
                }
            } ); }
public void soundPlay(MediaPlayer sound) {
  {   sound.start();
      sound.setLooping(true); }

buttonMusicStop = findViewById(R.id.buttonMusStop);
    buttonClick2();}
private ImageButton buttonMusicStop;
public void buttonClick2() {
    buttonMusicStop.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    soundPlay2(musicSound);

                }});}

public void soundPlay2(MediaPlayer sound) {
    if (sound.isPlaying()) {
        sound.pause();

    } else {
        sound.start();
        sound.setLooping(true);
    } }
```

Hello! I start music in my application, but when I minimize the application, the music does not stop. What do I need to write so that when the application is minimized and also when the screen is turned off, the music stops. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You have two requirements here, what is on your onStop() lifecycle? You should use mediaplayer.stop() and then mediaplayer.release(). For detecting if screen is turned off you need to write a BroadcastReceiver.

Answer (score 0):

Seem your app is playing in background. So create onResume and onStop to stop play and release resource, somethings look like this

```
onStop{
  sound.stop();
  sound.reset(); 
  sound.release();
  mediaplayer = null;
  supper.onStop();
}
```